# Como puedo comprimir la imagen antes de subirla?

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente código que sirve para subir una imagen a una carpeta en el servidor y guardar su ubicación en una base de datos, y funciona así:
Guarda la información en la base de datos la consulta retorna el id generado y procede a subir la imagen a la carpeta y una vez que este proceso haya terminado actualiza la base de datos para guardar la ubicación de la imagen, pero necesito insertar un script que me sirva para reducir el peso de la imagen y que mantenga la proporción, como puedo hacerlo?

```
    $sqlB = "INSERT INTO bt_bicis(idc, marca, modelo, color, marco) VALUES ('".$_POST['cliente']."','".strtoupper($_POST['marca'])."','".strtoupper($_POST['modelo'])."','".strtoupper($_POST['color'])."','".$_POST['marco']."')";     
$conB = mysqli_query($conx, $sqlB);
$idc = mysqli_insert_id($conx);

$ubi = "BOX/".$_POST['cliente']."/".$_FILES['foto']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], "../BOX/".$_POST['cliente']."/".$_FILES["foto"]['name']);

$sqlC = "UPDATE bt_bicis SET foto = '".$ubi."' WHERE id = '".$idc."'";      

if($conC = mysqli_query($conx, $sqlC)){

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $resp = array();
    $resp[] = array('ok' => 'si');
    echo json_encode($resp, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);    

}else{

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $resp = array();
    $resp[] = array('ok' => 'no');
    echo json_encode($resp, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

}
```

Comment: Hola. La pregunta, tal como está admite muchos enfoques. Pero, todo debe hacerse del lado del servidor, y preferiblemente al servirla por primera vez (**es mi opinión**). Puedes usar el método [imagecreate()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreate.php), para editarla, ponerle marcas de agua, etc. Revisalo, intenta usarlo y si encuentras dificultades modifica tu pregunta o plantea una nueva, al hacerlo dejarás de **buscar opiniones**

Comment: voy a investigar y te cuento

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería usar funciones de conversión de imagenes a formatos más ligeros sin perder demasiado en el intercambio. Por ejemplo, el formato webp si lo conoces, es uno de estos, quizás haya otros mejores, pero todo queda a tu juicio y lo que puedas encontrar.
Puedes consultar la documentacion del que te acabo de nombrar [imagewebp](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.imagewebp.php)

Comment: Graia voya leerlo y te cuento

Comment: Lo escencial esta escrito en la respuesta. De entonces en adelante es cosa del OP utilizar el mejor metodo que le pueda convenir. No haga sobremoderacion cuando el OP ya acepto el consejo.

Comment: En la página que recomiendas se encuentra esta nota: **As of today (end of january 2019), WebP is now supported across all the major browsers (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Opera).** Sugiero que traigas un par de sugerencias de uso. Aunque como indiqué a OP en mi comentario, se está actuando en el servidor y no del lado del cliente que es el punto nuclear de su pregunta.